# Julia: Find the indices of all maxima

Tags: max, julia, indices

In Julia you can use `findmax` or `indmax` to find the index of the biggest entry in a matrix. But if you have **multiple** entries with this maximum value, you get the index of the first one.
How can I get the indices of all max value entries in a matrix?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If this is not a bottleneck

```
A = [1, 2, 3, 3, 3]
A_max = maximum(A)
find(a->a==A_max, A)
```

Will give you what you need, but it does go over the array twice.

Comment: `find` can [no longer be found](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/search/?q=find) in the docs for v1.1.0.

Comment: As of now `findall(A .== maximum(A))` seems to work.

Comment: or `findall(x->x==maximum(A), A)`.

Answer (score 6):

You can also use comprehensions. The array will be iterated twice.

```
v = [1, 2, 3, 3, 3]
maxval = maximum(v)
positions = [i for (i, x) in enumerate(v) if x == maxval]
```

If performance is critical then the following algorithm may work:

```
function findallmax(arr)
    max_positions = Vector{Int}()
    min_val = typemin(eltype(arr))
    for i in eachindex(arr)
        if arr[i] > min_val
            min_val = arr[i]
            empty!(max_positions)
            push!(max_positions, i)
        elseif arr[i] == min_val
            push!(max_positions, i)
        end
    end
    max_positions
end
```

one iteration is required.

Comment: The performance of `findallmax`  depends heavily on the amount of new maxima found. I.e. `findallmax(1:2000)` takes 10 times longer than `findallmax(2000:-1:1)` and takes also longer than `findall(A .== maximum(A))` in this case.